# Get real shipping method from string

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I have this piece of code:

```
$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
//result is: mycarrier_mymethodcode
```

My problem is that it is a string, not an object. So I can not use the

```
$shippingMethod->getCarrierCode()
```

How can I get a real shipping method object like this:

```
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
 $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingMethod(true);
 //the true flag means returns with object not string
```

by my `mycarrier_mymethodcode` string?

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a custom shipping method,  mymethod. Sadly, magento2 uses as `carrercode_methodcode`. When I show my block, I should need to check, is this carrier is my carrier. I do not want to use `preg_*` funcitons. So I want to get the shipping method carrier code.

Comment: Later, I also need to get some items from my repositories by method code. I could hack the whole thing with regex, I just want to do not.

Comment: Want to for order or Quote?

Comment: Definetly quote. For order it's ok. I want to do this when I create an order at the dashboard, and no real order object exists.

Comment: " I create an order at the dashboard, and no real order object exists. " donot understand the word

Comment: What do not you understand? When you create a new order from the admin page, there is no `$order` while you do not save the order. There is only quote.